# Adding new property to file while commiting to GIT

Tags: git, svn, properties

SVN has feature to add custom property for each file commited using revpropset. You can get the properties values using log command.( Using PySVN)
Is there similar feature available for GIT?
I need add new property to set some additional information per file. I don't want add it in the log message.

Comment: There are gitattributes [1](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Attributes), [2](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes).

Comment: It might be helpful to describe specifically what your goal is with these properties, there might be another way to solve your issue.

Comment: SVN is able to store properties per file because SVN stores files. Git does not store files; Git stores commits. The only way to stuff properties in is therefore to put them into commits. For (much) more on SVN properties, see http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.props.html